# How to clear ghci's function result cache?

Tags: haskell, ghci

GHCI seems to cache the results of functions during an interactive session. It's easy to notice, just call a time-consuming function twice. On the second time, the result will appear immediately.

Is there a way to clear this cache from within GHCI so I don't have to restart it? I'm doing some quick'n'dirty non-detailed performance comparisons, so using System.CPUTime instead would be overkill.

Comment: Could you give an example of a specific function call that gets cached, please?

Comment: ``let f = 1 : map (2*) f`` and then ``last $ show $ f !! 200000``. On the first time, it takes about 15sec on my machine but is calculated immediately on the second time.

Comment: That's not a function.

Comment: That is just lazy evaluation.  In ML `let f = some_computation` would be evaluated once, when that line was first encountered.  In Haskell it is computed at most once when it is actually needed.

Comment: Guys, he's asking how to free values stored from previous steps in order to reclaim memory.  It is not a complicated question.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: Or "she" :)

Comment: I see, so if I evaluate ``take n f``, the first n values will be calculated **and** also stored in f. And as Gabriel commented, the question is how to remove those calculated values from the memory. Or to put it differently: How can I force GHCI to fully recalculate some expression without reusing any values from previous calculations?

Comment: `let f = undefined` will free it. If you want to use the definition of `f` over and over again while recalculating it every time, you can use a self-contained `let`-binding, i.e. `let f = ... in <calculation>` and change `<calculation>` for each different expression involving `f`. Finally, you could defeat memoization by making `f` polymorphic, e.g. `let f :: Num a => [a]; f = 1 : map (2*) f`.

Answer (score 14):

You can always reload the module you're working in via the command `:r`. This will throw away any interactive bindings you have made, and that might not always be practical if you're just poking around. This also works if you're not actually using a module.

Answer (score 5):

As the comments note, you're using `let` to bind a *name* to a *value* which is the *result of applying* a function. If you want to keep the value around, don't name it in a let! (or just don't refer to the value you've already computed in a let).

Comment: This isn't always simple -- for example, the example OP provided is recursive, so without `fix` it's hard to define without a `let`

Comment: `let f = foo f` will give a binding. `let f = foo f in f` will not. simple!

Answer (score 4):

GHCi has a `+r` option, which, [according to the manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-set.html#id489786), should do what you want:

> Normally, any evaluation of top-level expressions (otherwise known as
>   CAFs or Constant Applicative Forms) in loaded modules is retained
>   between evaluations. Turning on `+r` causes all evaluation of top-level
>   expressions to be discarded after each evaluation (they are still
>   retained during a single evaluation).
>
> This option may help if the evaluated top-level expressions are
>   consuming large amounts of space, or if you need repeatable
>   performance measurements.

Note that it talks about [constant applicative forms](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constant_applicative_form), not functions. However, I couldn't get it to work for your example:

```
Prelude> :set +r
Prelude> :set +s
Prelude> let f = 1 : map (2*) f
(0.01 secs, 1222216 bytes)
Prelude> last $ show $ f !! 100000
'6'
(3.54 secs, 641914476 bytes)
Prelude> last $ show $ f !! 100000
'6'
(0.04 secs, 1634552 bytes)
Prelude> last $ show $ f !! 100000
'6'
(0.04 secs, 1603568 bytes)
```

Apparently, [`+r` only works for compiled code](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1400), though the docs don't mention this.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize,

```
>>> :set +s  -- activate performance 
>>> :r       -- reset all interactive binding
Ok, modules loaded: none.
>>> :show bindings -- check the binding state
```

Let's start the test,

```
>>> let f = 1 : map (2*) f
(0.01 secs, 1543272 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
f :: [Integer] = _
>>> last $ show $ f !! 50000
'6'
(0.55 secs, 170011128 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
f :: [Integer] = 1 : 2 : 4 : 8 : 16 : ....
it :: Char = '6'
>>> last $ show $ f !! 50000
'6'
(0.02 secs, 1562456 bytes)
```

Using undefined,

```
>>> let f = undefined 
(0.01 secs, 565912 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
it :: Char = '6'
f :: a = _
>>> let f = 1 : map (2*) f
(0.01 secs, 513304 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 50000
'6'
(0.94 secs, 170517840 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
f :: [Integer] = 1 : 2 : 4 : 8 : 16 : ....
it :: Char = '6'
```

reset the binding,

```
>>> :r
>>> :show bindings 
Ok, modules loaded: none.
```

---

Another studie case,

```
>>> let h = (2*)
(0.01 secs, 590232 bytes)
>>> let f = 1 : map h f
(0.01 secs, 1138792 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
it :: Char = '6'
h :: Integer -> Integer = _
f :: [Integer] = _
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'6'
(1.69 secs, 241802432 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'6'
(0.03 secs, 2002432 bytes)
```

Still cached, change the binding of h to see,

```
>>> let h = (3*)
(0.01 secs, 547208 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'6'
(0.03 secs, 2029592 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
f :: [Integer] = 1 : 2 : 4 : 8 : 16 : ....
h :: Integer -> Integer = _
it :: Char = '6'
```

Do no matter, need to redefine f also,

```
>>> let f = 1 : map h f
(0.01 secs, 552048 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'1'
(4.36 secs, 374064760 bytes)
```

---

Using Let .. in ... binding,

```
>>> let f = let h = (2*) in 1 : map h f
(0.02 secs, 1068272 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'6'
(3.90 secs, 242190168 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'6'
(4.89 secs, 242271560 bytes)
>>> last $ show $ f !! 60000
'6'
(5.71 secs, 242196976 bytes)
>>> :show bindings 
h :: Integer -> Integer = _
f :: Num a => [a] = _
it :: Char = '6'
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER FOR 2019: It's not possible...